# Client/Server Application That Can Deploy Client From Server

Tags: c#, deployment, client-server

I have a client-server application written in c#. I am hoping someone can give some direction on where to look in order to set it up where a user could connect to the server from their workstation, most likely through http but that's not a requirement, and download the client. The mechanism would need the following features:

- Check for updates on client startup and automatically apply them.
- Allow multiple clients (connected to different servers) to download on the same machine
- Client can be downloaded by a non-local admin
- Possibly install any prerequisites needed on the workstation

I currently use ClickOnce but it isn't quite working out. Currently the server sits in IIS and uses WCF services.

Comment: What "isn't quite working out"? Please be more specific. Do you have a specific question about ClickOnce?

Comment: ClickOnce does about 80% of what we want to do but not all. For instance, in order to allow multiple clients on the same workstation, I had to "trick" ClickOnce by changing the name of application in one of the instances. Doing that however breaks COM interop, which the application could use, so instead we have to register COM components.

Comment: Multiple clients on the same workstation? WHY on earth would you do that?

Comment: Because different clients are connecting to different servers which have different sets of data.

Comment: and you're not using configuration files why?

Comment: If you would like more information in order to answer the question I will happily provide it but lets try to keep on topic.